# How do I call the datas outside the loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Error

> Undefined variable: aid1

Code

```
foreach($data1 as $row){
  if(preg_match_all("/value='(.*?)'/",$row,$aid)){
      $aid1 =$aid[1];
      $data_content =[
           "aid1" =>$aid1
      ];
  }
  array_push($aid1,$data_content);
}
print_r($aid1);
```

Comment: Looks as if your `preg_match_all` is never satisfied.  What is `$row` here?  If it's not a string, that's likely a problem.

Comment: if(preg_match_all('/<input type=checkbox name=AID(.*?)<input type=checkbox name=AID2/',$output,$data)){
                $data1 = $data[1];
               
                foreach($data1 as $row){

Comment: It's undefined because you are setting `$aid1` to the value of `$aid[1]` which appears to not exist in your case. Looks like your only getting 1 result in `$aid`. Try doing a `print_r` on `$aid` right inside of your `if` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here am not much clear about your code.But below code might be work for you.

```
$aid1 = '';
foreach($data1 as $row){
      if(preg_match_all("/value='(.*?)'/",$row,$aid)){
          $aid1 =$aid[1];
          $data_content =[
              "aid1" =>$aid1
          ];
      }
      array_push($aid1,$data_content);
}
print_r($aid1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define `$aid` variable blank before foreach loop as
 `$aid="";`